# SSRS Report Multi Parameters (start date,end date, MeterId, Displayby)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

In my SSRS report there are 4 parameters StartDate, EndDate, MeterId, & DisplayBy

Start Date: datetime datatype
EndDate   : datetime datatype
MeterId : is a drop down list and this will populate based on SQL query
DisplayBy: is a drop down list and this has the following values (Hour,day,Month & year)

[image]

The Database that stores hourly values for Meters, the following are the DB table columns: (MeterId,ReadingDate,Hours,Quantity,Price)

When I select the startdate, end date and the meter Id and display i want to show report based on the startdate & enddate and then by display values.

If the display is hour, the we got display all the 24 hour values  for the MeterId,Quantity, Price for the date range.

If the display is day, we got display total quantity and total price for the MeterId for that date range.

If the display is Month, we got display total quantity and total price for the MeterId for that date range.

If the display is Year, we got display total quantity and total price for the MeterId for that date range. Say for example If i select start date as 1-1-2016 and end date as 12-31-2016. My result should show 12 rows for each month with their total Quantity, Total price for that particular MeterID.

my DB table stores all the hourly values i know how to show the values on screen if the user selects the display dropdown as hour. But, dont know how to show the result for day/month/year or how to group it. Do I need to use "case" statement and if so what should i need to give on display parameters.

Please suggest your idea...

Row Grouping:
[image]

```
    SELECT I.CustomerName, I.ReadingDate, I.IntegratedHour, I.IntegratedUsage, I.IntegratedGeneration, DATEPART(dd, I.ReadingDate) AS [Reading Day], DATEPART(mm, 
                  I.ReadingDate) AS [Reading Month], DATEPART(yyyy, I.ReadingDate) AS [Reading Year]
FROM         IntegratedHour_MV90 AS I INNER JOIN
                      CustRptMeterExtract AS CT ON CT.CustomerName = I.CustomerName
WHERE     (I.ReadingDate >= @StartDate) AND (I.ReadingDate <= @EndDate) AND (I.CustomerName IN (@FacilityName))
```

Expected Result: 
[image]
[image]

SSRS Current Output: Doesnot match
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you tell us what your specific problem is. Currently you are just describing your project without asking any question.

Comment: I am sorry, since my DB table stores all the hourly values i know how to show the values on screen if the user selects the display dropdown as hour. But, dont know how to show the result for day/month/year. Do I need to use "case" statement and if so what should i need to give on display parameters. Bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your layout you could set row grouping to an expression something like this

```
=SWITCH
(
Parameters!ReportBy.Value=1, Fields!Hour.Value,
Parameters!ReportBy.Value=2, Fields!Day.Value,
Parameters!ReportBy.Value=3, Fields!Month.Value,
Parameters!ReportBy.Value=4, Fields!Year.Value,
True, 0)
```

This assumes you have already have the hours/days/months/years in your dataset, if not then you would have to replace the field references with expressions to return the relevant month etc.

Based on what I can see above you'll need to add a grouping level for Customer before the group expression. Also, you Quantity expression should be a sum something like this

```
=SUM(FIelds!IntegratedGeneration.Value)
```

You may still have a problem though. I'm assuming Price is a unit price, so it does not make sense to sum that too. To get round this, you should calculate the LineValue (Qty * Price) in your dataset then change the price expression to be something like

```
=(SUM(FIelds!LineValue.Value)/SUM(Fields!IntegratedGeneratio‌​n.Value))
```

and this will give you the average price.

However, this may be slow and personally I would do the work in your dataset. Again assuming you have the months, years in your table then you could do something like this.

```
--DECLARE @ReportBy int = 1 -- uncomment for testing

select 
    MeterID, Price
    , CASE @ReportBy 
        WHEN 1 THEN [Month]
        WHEN 2 THEN [Year]
        ELSE NULL
     END AS GroupByColumn
INTO #t
 from dbo.MyDataTable

 SELECT 
    GroupByColumn
    , SUM(Price) as Price
FROM #t
    Group BY GroupByColumn
    Order by GroupByColumn
```

This assumes your report parameter is called ReportBy, if not just swap the name out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Appreciate it. My dataset has the following (MeterId, ReadingDate, Hour, Price, Quanity, Reading_Day,Reading_Month, Reading_Year). On the Parameter, i set the Reportby as Integer and specified values for Hour as 1, Day as 2, Month as 3 and Year as4. Then on the RowGrouping I used your (Switch Statement).  It seems to be working but the result i get is not correct. Do it have to use both (Switch statement and Select query) on the SSRS report?

Comment: I only used the Switch Statement. Also, my DB Table doesnt not store Month or the Year. It has got the following Columns: Meterid, ReadingDate (dateTime), ReadingHour  (integer), Price decimal, Usage (integer).

Comment: you only need one or the other, the SSRS grouping can be slow that's why I suggested you might want to do the work in SQL. Can you add a screenshot of the table along with the grouping that appears at the bottom of the screen. Then if you can show a sample of data with your expected results that will help.

Comment: I couldn't use the SQL statement because the database table doesn't store Month & Year separately. We only have a column called "ReadingDate" and its datatype is DataTime. I also added the sample of required output screenshot which i am looking to show it using SSRS. Screenshots are added in the initial question itself.

Comment: Can you post your dataset query to. The sample data you posted does not match the expected results so I can't really see what you are getting. So, dataset query, sample data, current results based on the sample and expected results based on the sample.

Comment: on the original question i have posted the dataset query along with the screenshot of the expected result and the current ssrs report.

Comment: Based on what I can see above you'll need to add a grouping level for Customer before the group expression. Also, you Quantity expression should be a sum something like this  `=SUM(FIelds!IntegratedGeneration.Value)` . You may still have a problem though. I'm assuming Price is a unit price, so it does not make sense to sum that too. To get round this, you should calculate the LineValue (Qty * Price) in your dataset then change the price expression to be something like `=(SUM(FIelds!LineValue.Value)/SUM(Fields!IntegratedGeneration.Value))` and this will give you the average price.

Comment: I've updated the answer rather than add any more comments

Comment: Alan, Quantity and price both are separate. Its just a columns we want to show on the SSRS REPORT( populates whatever the value from the  SQL DB table) we dont have to calculate (Qty*Price) or store that in SQL Table.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is " add a grouping level for Customer before the group expression. "

Comment: @ Alan, I tried your updated answer looks like the hourly values for the selected date range gets summed up too which shouldnt do.  I use =SUM(FIelds!IntegratedGeneration.Value)